# Как сериализовать свойство класса, помеченного с аттрибутом [XMLText] как PlainText

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialize

Всем привет. Сериализую следующий класс в XML

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(Namespace="", ElementName="request")]
public class Request
{
    [XmlAttribute("guid")]
    public Guid Id;

    [XmlText]
    public string Body;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime? TimeResponce;
}
```

Делаю сериализацию объекта

```
Request request = new Request();
request.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

request.Body = "<goods><good name=\"Товар 1\"/><good name=\"Товар2\"/></goods>";

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request));

XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
{
    Indent = false,
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    DoNotEscapeUriAttributes = true,
};
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings))
{
    serializer.Serialize(xw, request, ns);
}

string value = writer.ToString();
```

На выходе получаю строку, где поле Body сериализовалось так, что все символы < и > заменились на соответствующие escape-последовательности **lt;** и **gt;**.

Каким образом сериализовать объект, чтобы свойство Body сериализовалось без замены символов в escape-последовательность, то есть воспринимал его как PlainText?

Спасибо.

Comment: Вам хочется странного, такого не должно хотеться. Расскажите вашу настоящую задачу. Зачем вам хочется получить невалидный XML? (Или валидный, но для совсем другого объекта?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> На выходе получаю строку, где поле Body сериализовалось так, что все символы < и > заменились на соответствующие escape-последовательности lt; и gt;.

Так и должно быть. Xml будет невалидным без этого.
Чем тебе помешало? Надеюсь, ты не достаёшь потом из него значения регуляркой?

Единственный способ поместить в xml текст как есть - это использовать CDATA.
Судя по гуглу, только при помощи атрибутов заставить сериализоваться как CDATA нельзя, надо писать кастомную сериализацию.

---

Хм.. Кажется понял. У тебя уже есть сериализованный в xml объект, и ты хочешь его поместить внутрь другого объекта как свойство, но не доставая из строки.

Тогда только кастомная сериализация.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", ElementName = "request")]
public class Request
{
    [XmlAttribute("guid")]
    public Guid Id;

    [XmlElement("Body")]
    public XmlElement BodyElement;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Body
    {
        get
        {
            return this.BodyElement.InnerXml;
        }
        set
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<goods><good name=\"Товар 1\"/><good name=\"Товар2\"/></goods>");
            this.BodyElement = doc.DocumentElement;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime? TimeResponce;
}
```

....

```
Request request = new Request();
request.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
request.Body = "<goods><good name=\"Товар 1\"/><good name=\"Товар2\"/></goods>";

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request));

XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
{
    Indent = false,
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    DoNotEscapeUriAttributes = true,
};
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings))
{
    serializer.Serialize(xw, request, ns);
}

string value = writer.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(value);

StringReader reader = new StringReader(value);
var deserialized = (Request)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Body);
```

Или, по желанию, оставить `Request.Body` простым полем/свойством и перенести парсинг в `get`/`set` для `Request.BodyElement`.

Comment: спасибо, попробую.